# How to prevent exception breakpoints firing within a static library

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, static-libraries

I've created a small static library for Mac OS and iOS, and it's working very nicely thank you. However, during testing, there were times when my code bugged out and it hit a breakpoint that I keep set on 'All Exceptions' in case of just such an eventuality. I'm not worried about the bug itself - all the ones I know of are fixed - I'm more worried that Xcode took me straight to the code that crashed - *inside* my library's code, thus revealing the inner workings of my library's .m file.

Naturally I don't want this to happen in the wild, or people would be able to rip my code directly. How do I prevent Xcode from displaying the internals of my static library, even when an exception occurs within it?

-Ash

Comment: What about removing debug symbols and optimizing?

Comment: That didn't work sadly, but thanks for pointing it out as I had forgotten to switch my build settings to release instead of debug. For reference, I'm stripping debug symbols and optimisation is set to s.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an example of Xcode being a little too clever for its own good. It was actually detecting that I had the code for this library on my computer and fetching it directly from the folder, not reading it from within the library at all! I renamed the folder containing my library's source code and project file temporarily and, lo and behold, the library code is no longer displayed when a crash occurs!

Freaky.